# Create a column which is True for the primary key if the value in an other column is the highest, False if it is not

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I work on a big dataframe(with 70+ columns) where I have 'number' and 'pk' columns. I want to add a new column to the dataframe, which has True if the 'number' is the highest in its column for the 'pk', False if it is not.

Let's assume that I have a spark dataframe(dm1) contans only 'number' and 'pk' for the sake of simplicity:

```
number     pk
100        k1
200        k2
300        k3
400        k4
330        k3
500        k5
220        k2
370        k5
180        k2
90         k1
470        k4
```

I would like to have a third column, lets say "highest_check", where it is True if the 'number' for 'pk' is the highest number or False if it is not.

My Approach:

I tried to create an other dataframe(dm2) containing the pks with highest numbers, then tried to update the first dataframe(dm1) by matching the numbers&pks of the second dataframe.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('pk')
dm2 = dm1.withColumn('maxnumber', F.max('number').over(w))\
    .where(F.col('number') == F.col('maxnumber'))
```

This resulted the dataframe like this:

```
number     pk     maxnumber
100        k1      100
200        k2      200
330        k3      330
470        k4      470
500        k5      500
```

Then I tried to somehow update the first dataframe with True for the rows that are common in both df, and with false for that are not, using this:

```
dm1 = dm1.withColumn("highest_check", F.when(dm2.pk==dm1.pk& (dm2.number==dm1.number), True).otherwise(False))
```

But this approach failed.

What I want to have as a result, looks like this:

```
number     pk  highest_check
100        k1      True
200        k2      False
300        k3      False
400        k4      False
330        k3      True
500        k5      True
220        k2      True
370        k5      False
180        k2      False
90         k1      False
470        k4      True
```

Answer (score 1):

Ich used pandas
see here the result of Dataframe operations:

```
import pandas as pd

DF_INPUT = {
    'pk': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k3', 'k5', 'k2', 'k5', 'k2', 'k1', 'k4'],
    'number': [100, 200, 300, 400, 330, 500, 220, 370, 180, 90, 470]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DF_INPUT)

_max = df.groupby('pk')['number'].max()
df = pd.merge(df, _max, left_on='pk', right_on='pk', how='left', suffixes=['', '_max'])
df['highest_check'] = df.number.eq(df.number_max)
```

and here the final content of the dataframe:

- pk  number  number_max  highest_check
- 0   k1     100         100           True
- 1   k2     200         220          False
- 2   k3     300         330          False
- 3   k4     400         470          False
- 4   k3     330         330           True
- 5   k5     500         500           True
- 6   k2     220         220           True
- 7   k5     370         500          False
- 8   k2     180         220          False
- 9   k1      90         100          False
- 10  k4     470         470           True

Explanation:
line 3: import a dictionary to pandas dataframe
line 4: groupe the 'pk' and find the maximum per pk (same result as in your question) -> _max is a Dataframe too
line 5: perform a merge and combine the both Dataframes by pk, this is adding the column 'number_max', write back to df
line 6: create the column 'highest_check' by comparing the columns 'number' and 'number_max', if equal set True, else False.

Comment: This approach looks good and works for me. Thanks a lot. However, I created the first df with spark such as:
dm1 = spark.createDataFrame([(100 ,'k1'),(200 ,'k2'), ....)],['number','pk']).
The thing is, I already have a constructed spark df. I can convert spark df to pd df, apply this approach and change it back to spark df, but as you might agree, this would take considerable amount of computing power and cost.
Is there any way we can implement the same approach with spark, not using pandas ?

Comment: sorry @Hotpacalypse I have no idea about pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you get col not iterable error.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pandas as pd
w0=Window.partitionBy("pk").orderBy(lit("A"))
DF_INPUT = {
    'pk': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k3', 'k5', 'k2', 'k5', 'k2', 'k1', 'k4'],
    'number': [100, 200, 300, 400, 330, 500, 220, 370, 180, 90, 470]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DF_INPUT)
sp_df=spark.createDataFrame(df)
sp_df=sp_df.withColumn("highest_check",F.col("number")==F.max(F.col("number")).over(w0))
sp_df.show()
```

Comment: I get a 'Column is not iterable' error on the line where we add "highest_check" column.